# Add invoice expiry date on invoices automatically

Tags: magento

I have an invoice or order phtml files where the date is defined like this

`$this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'long'))`

I would also like to add another field that would take this order date and add 5 days to it. So the pseudo code could look like this

`$this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate() . "+ 5 days", 'long'))`

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually figured it myself. My pseudo code is almost the right code

```
$this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate() . "+5 day", 'long'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the sales_order_save_before event and set in the observer your custom date in your new field which was created using a mygento setup routine.

Instrutions for working with events can be found on magentocommerce: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Also for how to create a setup script to extend the standard model fields: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources

Comment: I think this is not related to my question. Answered myself.